# Как достать переменную из require JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

В проекте на Node.js и Express
Вынес блок с редиректами в отдельный файл.
И добавил в server.js:

```
require('./server/routes')(app,db);
```

В routes.js есть:

```
module.exports = function (app,db) {
  //константы и другие редиректы 
  ...

  app.get('/', checkAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
   res.render('index.ejs', { username: req.user.username });
   username = req.user.username;
  });

  ...
}
```

Как мне в server.js получить этот username?
Пробовал обьявлять до require, но после он null..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте `locals` для работы с переменными приложения.

```
// routes.js
...
app.locals.username = username;
...

// server.js
...
console.log(app.locals.username);
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое! Помогло!